# How to work with PS5 DualSense's haptics on Mac OS or iOS?

Tags: ios, macos, fmod, playstation5

FMOD's latest release a few weeks ago has some great new features for authoring haptics!

[Detailed Revision History discussing features](https://www.fmod.com/resources/documentation-studio?version=2.02&page=welcome-to-fmod-studio-revision-history.html).

However, the features are only available on Windows, not Mac. While there is now compatibility on MacOS/iOS/TV OS with the DualSense, the haptics are not yet compatible. After reaching out to FMOD, they confirmed that currently Mac OS does not expose those audio channels on the DualSense (it has 4 channels of input: 2 for L/R actuators and 2 for the controller's speakers). The PS5's DualSense is just about as good as it gets in haptics right now, and it would be awesome not only to be able to author haptics on Mac, but also to be able to have haptics running natively on iOS games + DualSense!

It seems that if extending Mac OS's compatibility with DualSense's haptics was something that could have been done easily, it would have been done by now. So my question, for any OS/firmware experts out there: would it even be possible to achieve this with some kind of Mac OS extension or driver to make it possible to author haptics in FMOD for Mac? How can I try to implement this feature?